# When I load PIV in VIM it ruins my NERDTree and it ruins my leader key

Tags: vim, plugins, remap

I'm working my way into VIM. I've got Pathogen, NERDTree and snipmate running, now I want to get PIV going. When i throw it into my bundle dir it loads and when i open php files they are folded by default. Great! But Nerdtree loses all it's colors, and my colon key which I remapped to be the semicolon also gets changed. Any idea what's going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To investigate that kind of issue you can use :

- `verbose map` to display all the keys and in which file they are mapped
- `verbose highlight` to display all highlighted groups

If you have an issue with the key ","
you can also use `verbose map ,`

You can try both commands with or without PIV and see what is different. Hopefully, you'll understand why and how you can work around it.

Comment: Thank you for the "verbose" tip !

Comment: Thanks, I'll report back if I get it fixed.